# How to remove lines at the ends of the range when using geom_freqpoly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

recently I am doing some graphs

```
raw%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=number_of_reviews))+
  labs(title = "Number of reviews",
       y="Frequency",
       x="Number of reviews"
  )+
  geom_freqpoly(bins = 10)+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

Here is my result
[image: pic]

I don't know why there is a line that shows the number smaller then 0. I have double checked that there is no value smaller than 0.
How can I remove this line?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_freqpoly` calls `stat_bin` with option `pad=TRUE` which adds "empty bins on either side of x" (see `?stat_bin`). To remove these bins you can call `stat_bin`directly with option `geom="path"` and `pad=FALSE` (which is the default for `stat_bin`).

Using some radnom example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

set.seed(42)
raw <- data.frame(
  number_of_reviews <- sample(0:200, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(raw, aes(x=number_of_reviews))+
  labs(title = "Number of reviews",
       y="Frequency",
       x="Number of reviews"
  )+
  stat_bin(bins = 10, pad = FALSE, geom = "path")+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Is there any other way to do this without changing geom_frepoly()? I tried to do geom_frepoly(pad = FALSE), but it didn't work. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately no. Adding pad=FALSE to geom_freqpoly was also the first thing I tried. Is there any reason you want to stick with geom_freqpoly? Because in the end geom_freqpoly is calling stat_bin under the hood.